# How do I import a json file(a json string of linebot's flex message)

Tags: python

**Though there is an error message about cp950, but I am not intent to find a way to solve it. Insead I am more curious about are there any other ways to do** besides what I have tried?(if I have making the confusion on the purpose)

I'm trying to write a line messenger program. Its message structure, which called flex message is a json string. I **plan to save the json string as a json file, and then import to the py file**. I would like to ask, how can I import it to the py file so that it can be successfully executed.

The jsone file will look like this:

```
flex_message={
    "type": "bubble",
    "header": {
        "type": "box",
        "layout": "vertical",
        "contents": [
        {
            "type": "box",
            "layout": "horizontal",
            "contents": [
            {
                "type": "image",
                "url": "https://scdn.line-apps.com/n/channel_devcenter/img/flexsnapshot/clip/clip4.jpg",
                "size": "full",
                "aspectMode": "cover",
                "aspectRatio": "150:196",
                "gravity": "center",
                "flex": 1
            },
            {
                "type": "box",
                "layout": "vertical",
                "contents": [
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "url": "https://scdn.line-apps.com/n/channel_devcenter/img/flexsnapshot/clip/clip5.jpg",
                    "size": "full",
                    "aspectMode": "cover",
                    "aspectRatio": "150:98",
                    "gravity": "center"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "url": "https://scdn.line-apps.com/n/channel_devcenter/img/flexsnapshot/clip/clip6.jpg",
                    "size": "full",
                    "aspectMode": "cover",
                    "aspectRatio": "150:98",
                    "gravity": "center"
                }
                ],
                "flex": 1
            },
            {
                "type": "box",
                "layout": "horizontal",
                "contents": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "{}, {}筆".format(p2_2,u),
                    "size": "xs",
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "align": "center",
                    "gravity": "center"
                }
                ],
                "backgroundColor": "#EC3D44", 
                "paddingAll": "2px",
                "paddingStart": "4px",
                "paddingEnd": "4px",
                "flex": 0,
                "position": "absolute",
                "offsetStart": "18px",
                "offsetTop": "18px",
                "cornerRadius": "100px",
                "width": "99px",
                "height": "25px"
            },
            {
                "type": "box",
                "layout": "horizontal",
                "contents": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "最高價格:NT${}".format(maxC_price),
                    "contents": []
                }
                ],
                "position": "absolute",
                "flex": 0,
                "width": "190px",
                "height": "20px",
                "offsetStart": "26px",
                "cornerRadius": "10px",
                "offsetTop": "50px"
            },
            {
                "type": "box",
                "layout": "horizontal",
                "contents": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "最低價格:NT${}".format(minC_price)
                }
                ],
                "position": "absolute",
                "flex": 0,
                "width": "190px",
                "height": "20px",
                "cornerRadius": "10px",
                "offsetTop": "70px",
                "offsetStart": "26px"
            },
            {
                "type": "box",
                "layout": "horizontal",
                "contents": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "平均價格:NT${}".format(meanC_price)
                }
                ],
                "position": "absolute",
                "flex": 0,
                "width": "190px",
                "height": "20px",
                "cornerRadius": "10px",
                "offsetTop": "90px",
                "offsetStart": "26px"
            }
            ]
        }
        ],
        "paddingAll": "0px"
    },
    "body": {
        "type": "box",
        "layout": "vertical",
        "contents": [
        {
            "type": "box",
            "layout": "vertical",
            "contents": [
            {
                "type": "box",
                "layout": "vertical",
                "contents": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "contents": [],
                    "size": "xl",
                    "wrap": True,
                    "text": "最近一筆交易:{}".format(p2_1),
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "weight": "bold"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "屋齡(年): {},  NT${}".format(p2_3,p2_4),
                    "color": "#ffffffcc",
                    "size": "sm"
                }
                ],
                "spacing": "sm"
            },
            {
                "type": "box",
                "layout": "vertical",
                "contents": [
                {
                    "type": "box",
                    "layout": "vertical",
                    "contents": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "contents": [],
                        "size": "sm",
                        "wrap": True,
                        "margin": "lg",
                        "color": "#ffffffde",
                        "text": p2_0
                    }
                    ]
                }
                ],
                "paddingAll": "13px",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff1A",
                "cornerRadius": "2px",
                "margin": "xl"
            }
            ]
        }
        ],
        "paddingAll": "20px",
        "backgroundColor": "#464F69"
    }                  
}
```

This is how I write in the py file, but it is not working:

```py
with open('flex_message.json', 'r') as f:
    flex_message_dict = json.load(f)
flex_message = FlexSendMessage.new_from_json_dict(flex_message_dict)
line_bot_api.reply_message(tk, flex_message)
```

The error message tells a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950'`

After I edit to utf8, this is the error message:

```py
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 49 column 38 (char 1629)
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 by any chance? Python 3 should default to using UTF8 encoding but the error suggest your program used cp950.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I am using Python 3, the error message really confused me. So I rather seek for a new way to import. Thank you fro the reply!

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify encoding as well

change this

```
with open('flex_message.json', 'r') as f:
```

to

```
with open('flex_message.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tries what you've suggest. There is an error message came along with"json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:" But if possible, do you have anyother ideas to import this json file?

Comment: @april looks like you have invalid delimiter at line 49 column 38.
Make sure your json is correctly formatted

Comment: When this json string is on the py file, it works perfect. So I wonder maybe the way I import may not be correct. However the string itself is correct.

Comment: can you attach your json file?

Comment: it say delimiter on its error message, but acutally it is a arguments come from the varible on the py file.